# php read from file float

Tags: php, arrays, string, floating-point

Hello I have a text file with three lines. every line has a float number.
How can I take each value and put in a float variable even if array?

For example text file is like the following

```
+3.01\n
-0.0012\n
-0.1\n
```

I want an array [if it possible] which save the values as float not as string.

Thanks

Comment: what prevents you from reading values into array and then loop over it and cast values to floats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$fileArr = file($fileName);
$fileArr = array_map('floatval', $fileArr);
```

Comment: could make it a one-liner `$fileArr = array_map('floatval', file($fileName));`